# IAM policy to restrict users to instances in a specific VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to make a `IAM policy` to restrict user access to all the instances in a specific `VPC`. Following policy I made but not working.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1450441260778",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region:Account_num:vpc/vpc-id"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have filled the corresponding `account_num` and `vpc-id` in the policy.

Comment: There is a typo in "Resource". You have misspelled 'region'.

Comment: @helloV That should not matter, as I have replaced the region with the actual region in which the vpc is created.

Comment: Sorry. That was typed in a haste. Is this the only policy attached to the user?

Comment: @helloV yes the poicy is attached and after attaching it to the required group, the instances are not even getting listed from the corresponding account.

Comment: It's quite a bit more complicated than this - see http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1ZU3LW4LLPQY2/How-to-Help-Lock-Down-a-User-s-Amazon-EC2-Capabilities-to-a-Single-VPC

Comment: There is an example to restrict access to specific VPC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html#example-bucket-policies-restrict-access-vpc

Comment: That example is for s3. but it should work for your case as well. If it works, I will add it as an answer and you can accept it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only thing you need to change is resource type to ec2 instead of s3.

Comment: @Sri.U Thank your for the suggestion. The policy is working and the confusion before was due to the enabled options on AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to restrict the user access and you have used the `allow` attribute which will give permission to access the instance . Is that the desired behavior ?

If you really want to restrict try `"Effect": "Deny"` in same policy .

However if you want to give access to certain users here's how you can do it .

The following below policy works for me well in that case. I use it for the developers to restrict the access to start stop the instances . You can add as many permissions as you want in the second block .

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances*",
                "ec2:StopInstances*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:ACCOUNT_ID:instance/i-32ds2a29"
        }
    ]
}
```

`ap-southeast-1` is the region for my case . 
To control an instance in a specific vpc you can simply use its id .There is no separate arn for vpc+instance_id instead you can use `arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/instance-id` as arn [refer this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-ec2)  .

Similarly you can use the same policy to restrict the users in specific vpc by using `arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:vpc/vpc-id` as arn, adding Action `ec2:*` and `deny` in effect .

Comment: It works and I noticed that AWS has a flaw in the user interface. I guess the previous policy will also work. As even after applying policy the AWS interface shows the option to terminate the instance which is not allowed in our policy but. When you go on terminating the instance than AWS alert you that you are not authorized to perform the action.

Comment: Its not a flaw but its by design . By setting any of the policy in aws the option on the view is never disabled while what disabled is from the api call you make to perform certain actions. Its same across all of the features . (They show all possible actions but you can only do what you are allowed to ) .

Comment: yeah @Ankit Kulkarni, I understand that the view should not get wiped off but it should be get disabled. The option should be there to see the possible options available but should be disabled if the user do not have enough permissions.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain permissions that cant be applied to a specific resource. These permissions will show an error when you check the policy in IAM.

In order to restrict a user to a specific VPC and allow all EC2 actions, the following policy can help you in achieving that:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "NonResourceBasedReadOnlyPermissions",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "iam:GetInstanceProfiles",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "IAMPassroleToInstance",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/VPCLockDown"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowInstanceActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:DetachVolume"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceProfile": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/VPCLockDown"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "EC2RunInstances",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceProfile": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/VPCLockDown"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "EC2RunInstancesSubnet",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:subnet/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:vpc/vpc-7bcd371e"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "RemainingRunInstancePermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::snapshot/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:key-pair/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:security-group/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "EC2VpcNonresourceSpecificActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
            "ec2:DeleteRoute",
            "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:vpc/vpc-7bcd371e"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

In order to understand in detail what each statements are doing, I would recommend reading [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-help-lock-down-a-users-amazon-ec2-capabilities-to-a-single-vpc/) from AWS. This policy, allows the user to:

- Sign in to the AWS Management Console and go to the Amazon EC2 console.
- Launch an EC2 instance as long as they:

  > Specify a subnet in the proper VPC.
  >   Specify the allowed instance profiles.
- Start/stop/reboot/terminate/attach volume/detach volume on an instance as long as they:

  > Specify an instance launched with the proper instance profiles.
- Delete security groups, routes, route tables, network ACLs, and ACL entries as well as authorize and revoke security group ingress and egress rules, as long as they are in the proper VPC.